# Trouble configuring azure app service from publish in Visual Studio, can't access endpoints

Tags: .net, azure, api, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

I am trying to post a simple .net 5 API, no front end, to my azure app service. I published from Visual studio to the existing app service. When I publish, it produces all the .dlls and .exe to the wwwroot folder. When I try to access my endpoints, I'm getting a 500 error.

[wwwroot folder with all posted files.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQUr8.png)

[path mapping in configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBe7i.png)

Comment: What is the 500 details ? Could you post the error details please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to log the error first and send post the error message for further analysis.
To generate the error log follow the below staps -

Go to the **SCM site** of your app service - https://yoursitename.scm.azurewebsites.net
or from the navigation blade use **App Service Editor**

- Navigate to the application deployment directory and find the `web.config` file
- Set `stdoutLogEnabled` to true change the
- `stdoutLogFile` path to point to the logs folder (for ex:.\logs\stdout)
- Save the `web.config` file and make a request to the app
- Navigate to the `d:\home\LogFiles` file, it should give a good idea of what is causing 500 error.

A detailed steps can be found in this link -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/202561/azure-web-app-net-core-start-up-error-how-to-find.html

Comment: thank you, this helped me figure out what the error was.